# Access a pointer from a child thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, v8

I have a struct that looks like this:

```
struct Work {
  uv_work_t requst;
  Local<Promise::Resolver> resolver;
};
```

I then have this method which crops an image with imagemagick:

```
void MagickNode::Crop(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args) {
  // Create a promise
  Local<Promise::Resolver> resolver = v8::Promise::Resolver::New(i.isolate);
  args.GetReturnValue().Set(resolver->GetPromise());

  // Create a worker
  Work *work = new Work();
  work->requst.data = work;
  work->resolver = resolver;

  // Do work
  uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), &work->requst, [](uv_work_t *req) {
    // Do the heavy lifting
  }, WorkVoidComplete);
}
```

When the process is complete, I want to resolve the promise. Which I do here:

```
void MagickNode::WorkVoidComplete(uv_work_t *req, int status) {
  // Setup the required items
  Isolate *isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
  v8::HandleScope handleScope(isolate);
  Work *work = static_cast<Work *>(req->data);

  // Resolve the promise
  work->resolver->Resolve(Undefined(isolate));
  delete work;
}
```

The problem, is that when `work->resolver->Resolve` runs it gives **Segmentation fault**. I think that this is because it is executed from a thread when it was created on the parent thread giving me no access.

How can I get access and run that line?

If I move that line to the end of the method `MagickNode::Crop`, it runs without error and the promise gets called.

Comment: I am not familiar with v8, but wouldn't `resolver` of `MagickNode::Crop` going out of scope somehow invalidate `work->resolver` to which it is assigned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `WorkVoidComplete` will actually be called in the loop thread. The problem here is that you're using a `Local<T>` handle instead of a `Persistent<T>` handle.

When the scope of `MagickNode::Crop` closes the local handle is released.

Changing your struct to use `v8::Persistent<Promise::Resolver>` will fix the problem. Note that when you're done with a persistent reference handle it must be manually released by calling `Reset()`.

```
class Work {
 public:
  Work(Isolate* i, Local<Promise::Resolver> r)
    : isolate_(i) {
      resolver_.Reset(i, r);
    }

  ~Work() {
    resolver_.Reset();
  }

  inline uv_work_t* request() { return &request_; }
  inline Isolate* isolate() { return isolate_; }
  inline Local<Promise::Resolver> resolver() {
    return resolver_.Get(isolate_);
  }

 private:
  Isolate* isolate_;
  Persistent<Promise::Resolver> resolver_;
  uv_work_t request_;
};

void Something(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
  Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
  Local<Context> context = isolate->GetCurrentContext();

  Local<Promise::Resolver> resolver =
    v8::Promise::Resolver::New(context).ToLocalChecked();

  Work* work = new Work(isolate, resolver);
  work->request()->data = work;
  uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), work->request(), DoWork, WorkComplete);

  args.GetReturnValue().Set(resolver->GetPromise());
}
```

Comment: Okay, I am trying that, but it isn't working. `Local<Promise::Resolver> resolver = Promise::Resolver::New(i.isolate);
Persistent<Promise::Resolver> presolver;
presolver.Reset(i.isolate, resolver);` and I get this error **error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'v8::Primitive *' to 'v8::Object *volatile '** then in the `WorkVoidComplete` I have this: `work->resolver.Get(work->info.isolate)->Resolve(Undefined(work->info.isolate));` Does that look right?

Comment: I had to change it to `Persistent<Promise::Resolver, CopyablePersistentTraits<Promise::Resolver>>`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Instead of making it copyable, just reset the one that already comes with your Work instance. `work->resolver.Reset(isolate, resolver)`

Comment: Could you please post an example in your answer, this is not working for me. I keep getting errors.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn i have updated my answer with an example